Deleting Extra Bone Shapes from Imported Rig?
I'm working on two rig projects that both use the same group of bone shapes, but the rigs are in separate files. However, if I use both rigs in the same scene, I want it so that they all reference the same set of shapes instead of needing two separate sets of bone shapes. Is there a way to replace all shapes en masse, so I don't need to replace the bone shape for each individual bone?
